# Can't find 'Apps & Data screen > Move Data from Android' option in IPhone XS

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to move contacts from Android but can't find the option in the IOS device. I'm following this websites:

[macworld](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iphone/how-transfer-contacts-music-photos-apps-from-android-iphone-move-to-ios-3459466/)
[Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201196)

[image]

Comment: Is it a new device you’re trying to transfer to?

Comment: Yes @Daniil Manokhin

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of the picture posted?

Comment: Show that I don't have any 'Apps & Data screen > Move Data from Android' option

Answer (score 1):

The articles you posted are for freshly setting up an iPhone.

You have two solutions:

**Transferring your contacts using an account**

You can send your contacts through WhatsApp or back them up using Google Cloud.

**Set up again**

You can return to the setup screen but this will erase all data.

To do this go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase all content and settings